# using std::equal_range to search the vector within some ranges

Tags: c++, search, stl

I have a std::vector with the element as pair and need to find all the elements with the first component within some ranges, for example, to find all elements such that abs(value of first component - reference)<0.01, I got the code from other post that

```
bool comp(pair<double, double> v1, pair<double, double> v2)
{
  return (abs(v1.first-v2.first)<0.001);
}

vector< pair<double, double> data;
for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
{
  double a, b; 
  // a & b are initialized randomly (the code was not shown here)
  data.push_back(make_pair(a, b));
}

// we sort the vector here based on the pair.first (code not shown)

// compval is used as reference value, i.e. we are going to find all elements with     abs(pair.first-ref.first)<0.01
pair<double, double> ref
ref.first = 0.5;
ref.second = 0.5;

std::pair< vector< pair<double, double>::iterator, vector< pair<double, double>::iterator> const range = std::equal_range(data.begin(), data.end(), ref, comp);
```

but if you look at all elements given by the resulting ranges, you will see that all elements of the data instead of the one satisfying abs(pair.first-ref.first)<0.01 will be returned. Is that anything I miss in the code? Thanks.

Comment: Failing to initialize `a` and `b` does not initialize them randomly - reading from uninitialized values invokes undefined behaviour.

Comment: Hi Mankarse, a and b are initialized randomly, I am just too lazy to show the code there. Sorry for that. Anyway, since there are only 10 elements in the vector, I print them out and compare them one by one, still, the searching algorithm doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`equal_range` requires a sorted range.

The order implied by your comparison function does not match the order that you sorted the range into - and so the call to `equal_range` has undefined behaviour.

For example - say your list contained `{{.5, 0}, {.6, 0}}` (these are sorted), and you then applied `std::bind(comp({.5,.5},_1))` to each element.

`comp({.5,.5},{.5,0})` would return true.

`comp({.5,.5},{.6,0})` would return false.

Your sort order is saying: "`.5` is less than `.6`", but at the same time your `comp` function is saying "`.6` is less than `.5`" (because a there is a value which is less than `.5` but not less than `.6`). This is contradictory, and the cause of your problems.

To actually find all the elements such that `std::bind(comp({.5,.5}, _1))` returns true, you could use `std::copy_if(data.begin(), data.end(), some_output_iterator, std::bind(comp(ref, std::placeholders::_1)))` (although there are a variety of different ways of doing this, depending on your exact needs).

Comment: It is confusing. So any way to modify the code to find the demanded elements?

Comment: @user1285419: You could use `std::partition(data.begin(), data.end(), std::bind(comp(ref, std::placeholders::_1)))`. If you do this then you don't need to sort the vector. The results you need will be between `data.begin()` and the return value of `std::partition`.

Comment: Thank you Mankarse. Using std::partition works but it is so slow. In my case, the vector contains over 200000 elements and the searching procedure will be repeated for many times.

Comment: @user1285419: `std::partition` has linear time complexity. It is asymptotically better than the "sort-then-equal_range" method that you were using. It is also asymptotically optimal (each element _has_ to be visited at least once in order to find all the elements which satisfy the predicate). (That said, there might still be a better way to achieve the actual end result that you are driving towards).

Comment: The way I am using now is simply sorting the vector first, and search the elements satisfying the requirement by a loop, since the vector is sorted, when we reach an element larger than the reference difference, break the loop. I don't know if this is good or not but comparing this to std::partition, seems partition takes about two times longer. But anyway, my way is still too slow, I still looking for faster way.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use `fabs` instead of `abs` in function `comp()`.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. But the prototype of abs takes double value and return double in my compiler. Anyway, I try fabs too, but doesn't work

Comment: but abs is a template function, it accepts double-type argument too

Answer (score 0):

Your comparison function does not satisfy the requirements of strict weak ordering, i.e. for two elements say a and b, if `comp(a, b) == true` then `comp(b, a)` should be `false`.

You maybe want something more like this:

```
struct Comp {
  double target;
  bool operator()(const pair<double, double>& lhs,
                  const pair<double, double>& rhs) const {
    return abs(lhs.first - target) < abs(rhs.first - target);
  }
};

vector< pair<double, double> > data;
data.push_back(make_pair(0.1, 1.0));
data.push_back(make_pair(0.15, 1.2));
data.push_back(make_pair(0.189, 2.1));
data.push_back(make_pair(0.19, -2.1));
data.push_back(make_pair(0.192, 3.1));
data.push_back(make_pair(0.2, 0.1));
data.push_back(make_pair(0.205, 0.1));
data.push_back(make_pair(0.205, 0.0));
data.push_back(make_pair(0.206, 12.1));
data.push_back(make_pair(0.21, -12.9));
data.push_back(make_pair(0.3, 3.4));
data.push_back(make_pair(0.5, 7.5));
// We *must* sort the vector using the same comparison function that we're
// about to use to get the lower and upper bounds
Comp comp;
comp.target = 0.2;
sort(data.begin(), data.end(), comp);

// Get the lower bound
pair<double, double> low(make_pair(comp.target, 0.0));
vector< pair<double, double> >::iterator lower =
    lower_bound(data.begin(), data.end(), low, comp);

// Get the upper bound
pair<double, double> up(make_pair(comp.target + 0.01, 0.0));
// N.B. use "lower_bound" here to get upper bound of target + 0.01 exclusive.
//      If we want to include target + 0.01, use "upper_bound"
vector< pair<double, double> >::iterator upper =
    lower_bound(data.begin(), data.end(), up, comp);

for_each(lower, upper, [](const pair<double, double> &data_point) {
  cout << data_point.first << "\t" << data_point.second << "\n";
});
```

which outputs:

```
0.2     0.1
0.205   0.1
0.205   0
0.206   12.1
0.192   3.1
0.21    -12.9
```

Comment: thanks Fraser. I tried your code for the following dataset (0.1, 1.0), (0.15, 1.2), (0.189, 2.1), (0.19, -2.1), (0.192, 3.1), (0.2, 0.1), (0.205, 0.1), (0.205, 0.0), (0.206, 12.1), (0.21, -12.9), (0.3, 3.4), (0.5, 7.5). I am searching all the points with x components between 0.19 to 0.21, i.e. with target = 0.2 It supposes to give me the following points but it shows an empty result actually (0.189, 2.1), (0.19, -2.1), (0.192, 3.1), (0.2, 0.1), (0.205, 0.1), (0.205, 0.0), (0.206, 12.1), (0.21, -12.9)

Comment: I edited the answer to match your data above.  It works fine for me.  (0.189, 2.1) should not be included in the results as it is > 0.01 from the target.  (0.19, -2.1) is excluded because you specified `< 0.01`, not `<= 0.01`.  To change the code to reflect `<= 0.01`, simply replace `...upper = lower_bound(data.begin()...` with `...upper = upper_bound(data.begin()...`.